# trouble with Vba Paste when filtered output is one row

Tags: vba, excel

I have a file that I use dynamic copy and paste vba, everything works fine but when the filtered output is only 1 row, the procedure paste that one row, replicating it all over the paste destination range (from Row 1 to the end). it only happens when the filtered output is one row.

Here's my copy code:

```
Select Filtered data Range("A1").Select 
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select 
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select 
If Selection.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count = 2 Then
     MsgBox ("Guess What! there are no break fix today, let's try again tomorrow") 
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
     openWb.Close 
     Exit Sub 
End If 
'Copy selected data 
Selection.Copy
```

Paste code:

```
Sub (PasteCopied data)

 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Renee's Report").Range("B:AD") _
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is you line to copy the data?

Comment: 'Select Filtered data

    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    
    If Selection.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count = 2 Then
    MsgBox ("Guess What! there are no break fix today, let's try again tomorrow")
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    openWb.Close
     
    Exit Sub
     End If
       
 'Copy selected data
 
    Selection.Copy

Answer (score 0):

This is just the way paste works in Excel.  If you do the copy and paste manually you will see the same behaviour, roughly -

- if the copied range is a single row, column or cell and the range pasted into has more than one row/column/cell (respectively) then Excel will repeat the copied cells to fill the paste range
- if the copied range is not one of the above then one copy gets pasted in at the top-left corner of the paste range

To fix it you just need to paste into a single cell:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Renee's Report").Range("B1") _
.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```